# Set value from multiple elements

Tags: javascript

I have id in input text like this, how I get id with `getElementbyId` from this multiple elements. I want to set in input text.

```
<input name="BRC_LST[{index}][prcold]" id="BRC_LST[{index}][prcold]" onfocus="tabklik();" value="<?php echo $row['LAST_PRC_X'];?>" class="barcode-prcold" type="text" size="20"/>
```

I tried to set 5 for example in input text. But result is nothing.

```
document.getElementById('BRC_LST[{index}][prcold]').value = 5
```

Comment: I [tested your code](https://jsfiddle.net/upmve08b/), and it seems to work for me.

Comment: What do you see in the console if you do `document.getElementById('BRC_LST[{index}][prcold]')`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dfzwet7p/